# using list values in an if statement to compare with a string

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have this list and string

```
list_var=(['4 3/4','6','6 3/4'])
string_var='there are 6 inches of cement inside'
```

i want to check through and find if any of the elements of the list is in the string

`if list_var in strin_var` (wont work of course due to the fact its a list but this is what i want to achieve is to compare all of the values and if any match return true)

i tried using any function but this not seem to work i would also like to achieve this without using loops as the code i will be using this in contains extracting data from a lot of files so execution speed is an issue

Answer (score 0):

you will have to iteratre over the list at least once as you are trying a search operation.

```
is_found = any(True for i in list_var if i in string_var)
```

works perfectly for this scenario.